# React router page doesn't reload

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a problem with `react-router`. The page content doesn't update when I click on a link (I'm using `Link` from `react-router`), although the URL is updated. Below is the source code:

```
React.render(
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Dashboard} />
            <Route path="phase/:phaseNo" component={PhaseDetail}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>, document.getElementById("glyco-edu")
);
```

PhaseDetail.js:

```
var React = require("react");

var PhaseDetail = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return( <div>
                Example Text
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = PhaseDetail;
```

Link element:

```
<Link to={'/phase/'+this.props.phaseNo}>
   {images}
</Link>
```

I'm using `react-router-1.0.0-rc3` and `react-0.13.3`.
Thank you.

Comment: If you type directly into the browser `http://<host>/phase/123` do you land on the `PhaseDetail`?

Comment: No. There will be some 404 error. The url always contain a '#'. `http://<host>/#/phase/123` will show the default page instead of `PhaseDetail` though.

Comment: Try to take out the `<IndexRoute>` and see if it routes correctly.

Comment: I did. It still doesn't route correctly.